# Adding a Firestore document as part of a document update

Tags: angular, collections, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to create a new document in one collection as part of an update to a document in another.

Simple version. User updates the status on a task by clicking a button.

What I need to happen is this

```
completeTask(task:ITask) : Promise<any>
{
  const userId = this.auth.userId;

  this.afs.collection('Tasks').doc(task.id).update({Status: 'COMPLETE'});
  this.afs.collection('Notifications').add({Task:task.id, Status: 'COMPLETE', UserId: userId});
  // ...
  // return Promise here;
}
```

The above needs to happen as part of a single operation.
I have read through all I can find on both Batch and Transactions but can't seem to find how to do this properly.
I can just run them sequentially and return a

```
Promise.all(taskPromise, notifyPromise);
```

or chain the one off the other - but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two writes to happen as one operation (either both succeed, or neither happens), you should [use a batched write or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Promises are a client-side mechanism and thus are not an ideal way to achieve atomicity.

Comment: I would like to use either of those but I cannot find any samples that demonstrate how to create a new document. The Batch samples all show how to update multiple documents. I want to update one and create another - looking for a specific example (working code) on how to do that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#set and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set both contain this in their documentation: "Writes to the document referred to by the provided DocumentReference. **If the document does not exist yet, it will be created.**"

Comment: I know about those - my question was example code on how this works because when I follow the docs I get errors. When I get a ref to the various locations to update and set and use them in my service I get the error **Argument of type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'**. Hence my request for working code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for.
The problem with creating a document as part of a batch is that you have to generate your own key - either using one that you manage or getting one from Firestore. In hindsight this is obvious as the batch needs to work on a given document - I was getting distracted by the fact that .add() on a normal reference will add your new doc and give it an Id - I was looking for a way to do this with a Batch.

Here is the code I eventually ended up using

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {
  // AuthService is implied but not shown as part of this example
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private auth:AuthService) { }

  // Update Project and write an event log to the projects ActivityLog
  // as part of the same write
  UpdateProject(projectName: string, data:any) : Promise<void>
  {
    // Get a batch reference
    const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();

    // Reference to the Project document that needs to be updated
    const ref = this.afs.collection('Projects').doc(projectName);

    // Get a unique Firestore ID for the ActivityLog document
    const newLogId = this.afs.createId();

    // Reference to the ActivityLog doc using the ref and ID created above
    const logref = ref.collection('ActivityLog').doc(newLogId);
    batch.update(ref.ref, data);

    // Create the new entry
    batch.set(logref.ref, {
      Created: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
      User: this.auth.UserName,
      Action: 'Update', 
      Data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    return batch.commit();
  }
}
```

In my component

```
onUpdate(data:any) {
  this.projectSvc.UpdateProject(this.projectName, data)
    .then(() => alert('Update successful'));
}
```

The key bit was generating the Id and using that in the reference to the new ActivityLog (in this case) document.

Sidebar: This could potentially have been done as a Cloud Function - the reason we are even looking at this is that we need to know the user that made the change and based on research done you can't get the id of the user that triggered the change in Firestore (you can in Realtime I believe).